# How to calculate the sum of parent categories spend by the child category spend in hierarchical table structure?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view, oracle11g

I have the following table structure where i have stored the category and their sub-category in hierarchical format, in the table only the least category has the spend amount (SPEND).

[image: Table Structure]

Now i want to create a view or a SQL query by which i can also get the spend amount for every category level. Following is the result data which i want get.

[image: Table 2]

So please help me with the SQL query which can fetch the above result from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
select Level1, level2, level3, level4, level5, sum(spend)
from <your table name>
group by rollup(level1,level2,level3,level4,level5)
order by Level1, level2, level3, level4, level5
```

Comment: thanks Vasyl for your answer, its working fine but returning duplicate records, when i am running this sql then its returning 35 rows on the above table some rows with blank spend value, is it possible to return only one row for each and every subcategory with spend amount. this is the result link [link](http://http://postimg.org/image/6m1f9ddcz/)

Comment: Try to add `HAVING sum(spend) is not null` if I rightly understood you

Comment: i added `HAVING sum(spend) is not null` and the rows with null spend value eliminated but its again returning duplicate rows. this is the result link [link](http://postimg.org/image/qw6twyti5/)